# Can someone help me figure out how to combine function parameters to get multiple results?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have this function that returns a number...(the average) of certain calculations, like this:

Example1.......   My_function( x,2,3) => 56.5

Example2.......   My_function( x,3,7) => 42.2

Example3.......   My_function( x,8,23) => 40.3

The first "parameter" (or function argument "x") doesn't change, but I want to do combinations of parameter 2 and 3. And get the result of each combination of the same function to use only the results greater than 50. (in this case only the first example meets the criteria).

I would like to know if there is a way to combine parameters 2 and 3 with a for loop or something. Parameter 2 from 0 to 100 with parameter 3 from 0 to 100. And then be able to get all the parameters combinations of the function where give us a result above 50. I would really appreciate your help, I tried with for loop but I only get one result at a time and I don't know how to save multiple results.

As an example, I tried something like this to find the second parameter:

```
F1 = My_function(x,a,b)
for i = 0 to 100
    a := i
    if F1 > 50
        F1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using an array?
Your function could return an array of multiple values

```
My_function(x,a,b) =>

   a = array.new_float()
   for i = 0 to 100
      a := i
      if F1 > 50
         array.push(a, F1)

  _return = F1
```

Answer (score 0):

To store multiple results, you need an array.

If you really want to test all the possible combinations, you need to call your function within a nested for loop. This will come with a huge performance penalty which I believe Tradingview won't like and your script won't be executed.

Anyways, here is an example for you:

```
param_2_arr = array.new_int()
param_3_arr = array.new_int()

for i=0 to 100
    for k=0 to 100
        res = My_function(x, i, k)

        if (res > 50)
            array.push(param_2_arr, i)
            array.push(param_3_arr, k)
```